# it crash when I use ALSA lib's function `snd_pcm_readi`

Tags: c++, alsa

This is the function which I read data from micro, but why when I allocate buffer by call `new`, the application crash, if I use `malloc`, it ok

```
void AlsaMicrophoneWrapper::readThreadFunction()
{
    int bufSize = m_bitsPerFrame * m_frames; 
    // char *buf = new char(bufSize);//crash
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(bufSize);
    if (NULL == buf)
    {
        printf("Snd_ReadThread allocate mem error\n");
        return;
    }
    snd_pcm_sframes_t retFrame;
    ssize_t returnCode;
    while (true)
    {
        retFrame = snd_pcm_readi(m_pcmHandle, buf, m_frames);
        if (-EPIPE == retFrame)
        {
            snd_pcm_prepare(m_pcmHandle);
        }
        else if (retFrame > 0)
        {
            returnCode = m_writer->write(buf, retFrame);
            if (returnCode <= 0)
            {
                printf("Failed to write to stream.\n");
            }
        }
    }

    free (buf);
    return;
}
```

Comment: It has to be: `char *buf = new char[bufSize];` not `(bufSize)`. Also use delete if you use new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new char(bufSize)` allocates a single `char` and initializes it to `bufSize`. You want `new char[bufSize]`. And when you `new[]` something, you must `delete[]` it later, not `free` it.

```
char *buf = new char[bufSize];
...
delete[] buf;
```

---

To avoid having to manage memory manually, you could use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector`.

```
auto buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(bufSize);
// use buf.get() to access the allocated memory
```

Or

```
std::vector<char> buf(bufSize);
// use buf.data() to access the allocated memory
```

Comment: oh my god ,so stupid mistake, long time not use c++, thank you.